# asp net core - NullReferenceException: how to return mysql data reader from method?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, mysqldatareader

I've created a method to return mysql data reader.

```
public class DbHelper : BaseService
{
    public DbHelper(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    { }
    public static MySqlDataReader GetDataReader(string query)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                return reader;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and next I've written:

```
var query = ""; //here my query string
var rdr = DbHelper.GetDataReader(query);

while (rdr.Read())
{
}
```

but I receive a null reference exception on this line `return reader;`

`_connectionString` and `query` are valorized correctly.

How can I fix? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If the underlying connection used by the reader is closed then the reader cannot be used. This approach cannot work

Comment: @Steve do you mean the line `MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);` is not correct? If I use `CommandBehavior.Default`, it doesn't work anyway...

Comment: _" I receive a null reference exception on this line `return reader;`"_ -- that's not possible. A `return` statement just returns the value in the expression, in this case `reader`. If `reader` is `null`, you just get a `null` value returned. It's not going to throw an exception. I do agree with the comments explaining that you can't dispose your object before returning it and expect that to work. But your question doesn't describe a plausible error scenario in the first place. If `NullReferenceException` really is what you're asking about, see the marked duplicate. Otherwise, fix the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the using around the creation of the connection. When you exit from the using block everything is disposed. Thus the DataReader cannot work because it cannot use the connection disposed in the using block.

A first very simple workaround is to execute the loop inside the using block and at each loaded record call the delegate received in the input parameters

```
public static void FillWithDataReader(string query, Action<IDataRecord> filler)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
                filler(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

The caller could call the *FillWithDataReader* in this way

```
FillWithDataReader("SELECT something FROM somewhere", FillMyData);
.....

// This is called at each loop inside the FillWithDataReader    
public void FillMyData(IDataRecord record)
{
    string aSomething = record.GetString(record.GetOrdinal("something"));
    .....
}
```

Now the connection used by the reader to fetch records is still open and you can still separate the logic to extract data from the database from the logic used to fill your models or user interface objects.

Comment: Is there a way to return the mysql data reader before it is closed? Maybe using a special `CommandBehavior `?

Comment: If you remove the using around the connection and using the actual CloseConnection command behavior. But I advise you to not pursue this road.